# Simetrix TLV431 problem

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, simulation

I have a problem simulating a [TLV431](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tlv431) shunt regulator in Simetrix; I don't get the output voltage that I expect from the simulation.

Can somebody tell me where the problem is?

I am using the Simetrix model TLV431_V2.lb found on [this page](https://www.diodes.com/part/view/TLV431Q/#tab-details).

[image: Simetrix simulation]

[image: Simetrix voltage probe on output]

[image: mathcad calcs]

Comment: The difference between your schematic and the last picture is the load. Either remove it or make it `10k`, or greater. Otherwise, the current that's needed to drive it is too large compared to the current needed for the 431.

Comment: Increase R1 and R2 by a factor of 100, so make them 61.2k and 100k.  It says this in the datasheet just below the Figure 1 you snipped.